# Rails outputting data attribute as text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to add a font icon to a link using a data attribute.

This is my rails template

```
<%= link_to "Profile", current_user, :data => { :icon => '&#xe609;' } %>
```

This is what gets outputted in the html

```
<a data-icon="&amp;#xe61c;" href="/canvases/8">Preview</a>
```

For icons that work, this is what gets outputted (Notice the & is now a &)

```
<a data-icon="&#xe61e;" href="/canvases/8"></a>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data attributes are HTML encoded by default. This prevents [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). You can mark the string to be safe.

```
<%= link_to "Profile", current_user, :data => { :icon => '&#xe609;'.html_safe } %>
```

This is find for hard-coded strings. But be aware that it may be dangerous if you use user provided data.

Comment: Am I using user provided data? Yes? If so, is there an alternative solution?